# LINQ: Calling a Method from within linq?, my method returns an anonymous type

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects, anonymous-types

Can anyone help. I have the following as part of a LINQ, its working but the object MyObject returns an anonymous type. (I checked it in debug mode)

```
  {System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator<<>f__AnonymousType1<MyType.ParamRow,MyType.Row>,object>}
```

Here is part of my query

```
select new Param
{
   Name ="Test1",
   MyObject = (from o1 in otherObject.Object join o2 in otherObject.ObjectB on
                 o1.Id equals o2.Id
                   where o.Id == o2.Id select this.BuildMyObject("DataObject", o1))
}
```

I think i am using the select wrong....

Basically MyObject returns type of object but this

```
    select this.BuildMyObject("DataObject", o1)
```

returns an anonymous type. I want to create a real type of Object..

I think I am doing something wrong.

**EDIT**

Build my object is very simple currently I am returning a TextBox (textbox is a class of mine) as you can see it returns OBJECT

```
    private object BuildMyObject(string type, TestStructure.ParamRow item)
    {

        MyTextBox control = new MyTextBox();

        control.Name = "NotEmpty";
        return control

    }
```

Comment: Show us the BuildMyObject code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is how the compiler implements joins; it creates an anonymous type representing the various forms. You should be able to fix this in a select, for example:

```
select Tuple.Create(o1, o2);
```

or if you only need `o1`:

```
select o1;
```

Comment: Great marc, but tuple is .net 4 i think? I am stuck on 3.5 currently

Comment: also i am doing this   select this.BuildMyObject("DataObject", o1)
  and i calling my method that return OBJECT .... and i am passing a string a part of the linq join... but what is returned shouldn't be anonymous?? should be of type object?

Comment: @Martin - hard to say without seeing `BuildMyObject`... re 4.0, well. it only takes 2 seconds to whip up the moral equivalent of a tuple - it would even have better naming ;p

Comment: For example if change MyObject to read like this  MyObject = BuildMyObject("DataObject", p0)     i am passing in p0 which is in a query above. With this change it returns Object as i am not using it in a select, hope this makes sense

Comment: @Martin - not especially.... at the minimum it will be `IEnumerable<...>` since you haven't called First/Single/Last/etc

Comment: I can't believe i missed that :-)... yep i have to do First

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your MyObject, I believe all you are seeing here is the *concrete type* that is underpinning an `IEnumerable<object>`. This is because you aren't limiting to a single object. If you expect one row, tell it:

```
select new Param
{
   Name ="Test1",
   MyObject = (from o1 in otherObject.Object
               join o2 in otherObject.ObjectB on o1.Id equals o2.Id
               where o.Id == o2.Id select this.BuildMyObject("DataObject", o1)
              ).First()
}
```

Otherwise, just access `MyObject` as an `IEnumerable<object>`, and you should find that each row is actually a `MyTextBox`; i.e.

```
var sequence = (IEnumerable<object>) param.MyObject;
foreach(MyTextBox tb in sequence) {
    // should work
}
```

but note that this is different to it being an `IEnumerable<MyTetxBox>`; for that, you would use `.Cast<MyTextBox>()`